# Is `command-not-found` broken?

Tags: bash, terminal

There's a really great package that I love called [`command-not-found`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/command-not-found). When you type unknown commands, it searches through apt and suggests packages to install. [It has worked in Raspberry Pi before.](http://www.goliatone.com/blog/2015/03/05/raspberry-pi-command-not-found/)

However if you try it now…

```
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

Package is installed. According to docs you need to generate its database:

```
sudo update-command-not-found
```

It however finishes under half a second with return code 0, which is suspicious and strange. I've used it before in a full PC and it takes at least 20 seconds.

Then, no matter how many times I try to `update-command-not-found`, or restart my bash session, the database is never there.

```
$ aoeuaoeuaoeu
Could not find the database of available applications, run update-command-not-found as root to fix this
aoeuaoeuaoeu: command not found
```

If you `man update-command-not-found`, it references the file/folder (I dunno) `/var/cache/apt/apt-file`, which doesn't seem to be there at all. Should it? Or should `update-command-not-found` look elsewhere?

Comment: You might need to reload your shell to get it to work.  You can log out and back in or do `exec bash`.

Comment: I've wrestled with this for a while before coming to SE. Plenty of re-logins. Also the error message makes it clear that `command-not-found` _is_ in the session, it just has an empty database (which will remain empty). I will edit the message to make it clear that the session is different

Comment: Did you run `apt-file update` before updating the `command-not-found` cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer from the comment section**

Run `apt-file update` before running `update-command-not-found`

**Longer Answer**

The utility `command-not-found` includes a dependency on the `apt` search utility `apt-file`

```
#apt-cache depends command-not-found

command-not-found
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: apt-file
  Depends: python-gdbm
  Depends: lsb-release
```

So, on a system where `apt-file` has not been installed, installing `command-not-found` will also install `apt-file`.  However, `apt-file` is not the same program as `apt`, and seemingly does not rely entirely on the `apt-get update` cache.  So, in order to properly setup `apt-file` the `apt-file update` command is required.

There is a clue in `apt-get` output when install `command-not-found` and pulling in `apt-file` as a dependency.

```
#apt-get install command-not-found
...
Setting up apt-file (3.1.5) ...
The system-wide cache is empty. You may want to run 'apt-file update'
as root to update the cache.
```

Strangely, when paging through the `apt-file` manpage, the `update` command is listed as deprecated and results in a call to `apt update`.  I haven't looked too closely at the differences of where the package cache is stored or if there is some sort of identifier placed in the `apt` cache file to indicate that `apt` versus `apt-get` has been used to update the cache.  So, I'm uncertain as to *why* `apt update` is needed versus `apt-get update`.  I suppose it would be complicated to include updating the appropriate cache during the setup of `apt-file`, because dpkg is already running with a lock file.

Comment: Thank you. I figured reporting a usability bug about `update-command-not-found` was appropriate. https://github.com/zyga/command-not-found/issues/6